# What statistical analysis to used for kinetic data with multiple groups?

Tags: r, anova

In my data set I have two numerical variables Score which is the measurement performed, and the collection time (Time), also a categorical variable which is Treatment that contains 5 groups (A, B, C, D, and E). I performed a 2-way ANOVA for differences between collection time and different treatments. However, since to do this I converted time into a factor, I am not able to graph a scatter plot with a smooth line. I was only able to do boxplots. I am new to R, I don't know what kind of graph or statistical analysis is used for kinetic data. I just need to be point to the right direction to start learning how the kind of analysis that I want to do is called. Basically, I and trying to recreate the graph below with my data.
[image: This Graph is what I am ultimately trying to create with my data]

```
structure(list(Experiment = c("1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3", "1", 
"2", "3", "1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3", "1", "2", 
"3", "1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3", 
"1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3", "1", 
"2", "3", "1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3", "1", "2", 
"3", "1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3", 
"1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3", "1", 
"2", "3", "1", "2", "3"), Treatment = c("A", "A", "A", "CTRL", 
"CTRL", "CTRL", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "D", "D", "D", 
"A", "A", "A", "CTRL", "CTRL", "CTRL", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", 
"C", "D", "D", "D", "A", "A", "A", "CTRL", "CTRL", "CTRL", "B", 
"B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "D", "D", "D", "A", "A", "A", "CTRL", 
"CTRL", "CTRL", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "D", "D", "D", 
"A", "A", "A", "CTRL", "CTRL", "CTRL", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", 
"C", "D", "D", "D", "A", "A", "A", "CTRL", "CTRL", "CTRL", "B", 
"B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "D", "D", "D"), `Time (hrs)` = c(8, 
8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 
16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 
24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 
32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 
40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 
48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48), `Titer (log10)` = c(2.30102999566398, 
2.30102999566398, 2.22184874961636, 2.1249387366083, 2.1249387366083, 
2, 2, 2, 2.39794000867204, 2.17609125905568, 2.17609125905568, 
2.17609125905568, 2, 2, 2.30102999566398, 5.04139268515823, 5.04139268515823, 
5.23044892137827, 5.32221929473392, 5.32221929473392, 5.59659709562646, 
5.23044892137827, 5.23044892137827, 5.37106786227174, 5.14612803567824, 
5.14612803567824, 5.46239799789896, 4.86727101896545, 4.86727101896545, 
5.19033169817029, 5.69460519893357, 5.70757017609794, 5.98000337158375, 
6.14612803567824, 6, 6.11394335230684, 5.90848501887865, 5.80163234623317, 
5.8409420802431, 5.79239168949825, 5.78769656828987, 5.77815125038364, 
5.55630250076729, 5.71180722904119, 5.97772360528885, 6.46239799789896, 
6.60745502321467, 6.93951925261862, 6.67209785793572, 6.99343623049761, 
7.30102999566398, 6.41497334797082, 6.75204844781944, 6.68124123737559, 
6.14612803567824, 6.44715803134222, 6.60205999132796, 6.19033169817029, 
6.57403126772772, 6.73239375982297, 7.09691001300806, 6.69897000433602, 
7.04139268515823, 7.65321251377534, 7.38021124171161, 7.69897000433602, 
7.32221929473392, 7.17609125905568, 7.19033169817029, 6.7160033436348, 
6.72015930340596, 6.75587485567249, 6.84509804001426, 6.60745502321467, 
6.60745502321467, 6.9731278535997, 6.4983105537896, 6.93785209325116, 
7.65321251377534, 7.42596873227228, 7.60745502321467, 7.32221929473392, 
6.95424250943933, 7.26717172840301, 6.7160033436348, 6.43933269383026, 
6.49136169383427, 7.07003786660775, 6.60205999132796, 6.94448267215017
)), row.names = c(NA, -90L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest leaving hours post-infection as numeric and doing a linear model with a quadratic effect of time, crossed with the experimental group, something like

```
lm(response ~ poly(time,2)*exp_grp, data=...)
```

(polynomial coefficients by default will be for an orthogonal polynomial, hard to interpret: you could use `poly(time-mean(time), degree=2, raw=TRUE)` to get an ordinary polynomial on centered time instead ...)

To account for time-series nature of data, either check for temporal autocorrelation in the residuals or fit a model with autoregressive (e.. AR1="autoregressive order 1") errors, something like

```
library(nlme)
gls(response ~ poly(time,2)*exp_grp, data=... , 
          correlation=corAR1(form=~time|exp_grp))
```

([this old mailing list answer](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mixed-models/2011q3/016734.html) reminded me we have to use `form=` inside `corAR1`)

However, a quadratic model doesn't actually fit your data well - there's a big jump between the first and subsequent time points (see below). Fitting a quantitative, nonlinear function to your data (rather than assuming that each time point is a separate category) is more powerful, but also requires more assumptions.

```
gls(response ~ factor(time)*exp_grp, data=... , 
          correlation=corAR1(form=~time|exp_grp))
```

does appear to work (and doesn't make assumptions about the shape of the curve).  `car::Anova()` will be useful for inference.

For what it's worth, it doesn't really look like there was much autocorrelation to worry about in the first place, so you could go back to the plain old linear model ...

---

```
library(tidyverse)
dd2 <- dd %>% rename(time="Time (hrs)",titer="Titer (log10)") %>%
    mutate(Treatment=relevel(factor(Treatment),"CTRL"),
           trt_exp=interaction(Treatment, Experiment)) %>%
    mutate_at("time",as.integer)

 
ggplot(dd2,aes(time,titer,colour=Treatment)) + geom_point() +
    stat_summary(fun=mean,geom="line")

library(nlme)
m1 <- gls(titer ~ poly(time,2)*Treatment, data=dd2 , correlation=corAR1(form=~time|trt_exp))
plot(ACF(m1))
plot(m1,col=dd2$Treatment)

pframe <- with(dd2,expand.grid(Treatment=levels(Treatment),time=seq(min(time),max(time),length=101)))
pframe$titer <- predict(m1,newdata=pframe)

ggplot(dd2,aes(time,titer,colour=Treatment)) + geom_point() +
    geom_line(data=pframe)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I am having a bit of trouble when I input correlation=corAR1(~time|Treatment) I get Error in abs(value): non-numeric argument to the mathematical formula. When do you say exp_grp are you referring to a particular group or the list of all groups? Also if a remove the correlation then I do a QQ plot and a Shapiro test the data are not normal, should I worried for the normality of the data? Thank you again

Comment: `exp_grp` refers to the categorical (factor) variable that denotes the experimental group (as in the `lm()` formula above). As for the error, it's hard to say without a reproducible example. `?nlme::corAR1` does say that the time covariate has to be an integer ...

Comment: It says that specifying a time covariate t and, optionally a grouping factor, in this case, the treatments. A covariate for this structure must be integer-valued. I think it is since Time is numeric, and treatment is a grouping factor.

Comment: Can you please post your data in a *usable* format? (i.e., not screenshot; use `dput()` or post it somewhere: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Thank you for all your help Ben Bolker. I ended up just doing this. Yeah, these results don't appear to be very different until I reach collection 40 and 48 hrs. 
```{r}
model <- lm(Titer~factor(Time)*Treatment,data=...)
dd %>%group_by(Treatment)%>%anova_test(Titer~Time,error=model)
pwc <- dd %>%group_by(Time)%>%tukey_hsd(Titer~Treatment,p.adjust.method="bonferroni")
pwc
``` 
I will just take the results from the Tukey Hsd and make them manually in PowerPoint

Comment: I disagree pretty strongly with this approach; the difference doesn't suddenly appear at 40-48 hours, it's building up over time. (But, this is a *very* common approach, so it's hard to argue with it.)

Comment: I will study your answer more cautiously, this will build my understanding of the results and of R itself, Thank you for your kind answers and suggestions.